# Service Unavailable when asking for clientaccesspolicy.xml Composite WebRole in Azure

Tags: silverlight, azure, composite, webrole

I'm using the Composite WebRole approach to host 2 web apps in the same instance and webrole in Azure, one app is using Silverlight and needs to get (for many reasons) the clientaccesspolicy.xml from the root domain which is mydomain.cloudapp.net so it returns Service is unavailable error as expected.

Is there a way to catch the clientaccesspolicy.xml request and redirect it to my custom domain where my clientaccesspolicy file is available? or how can I enable my cloudapp.net domain using this approach? thanks

Comment: well I solved it by just adding another <Site> element and hostHeader set to my cloudapp.net, however, could there be a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

[Working with the Root Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395424.aspx)

[Enabling Cross-Domain Access to Blobs](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/uploading-windows-azure-blobs-from-silverlight-part-2-enabling-cross-domain-access-to-blobs)

Comment: Thanks but this is not related to Azure Storage

Comment: Sorry, I read it to fast. clientaccesspolicy.xml should be in the same place than your .xap file as far as I know.